# import csv into mysql via console yii (command line)

Tags: php, mysql, csv, yii

Im new in yii. i required to import csv file into mysql database via command line using yii 1.1

i have csv file :

```
name, age, location,
sirin,23,Mannarkkad/India
abdul majid,23,Mannarkkad/India
boby,25,Heringen / Helme
```

this is my action :

```
<?php

class ImportCommand extends CConsoleCommand
{
    public function actionImportCSV()
        {
           if (($handle = fopen(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/test.csv', 'r')) !== false) {
            // $i = 0;
            while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
                $model=TblUser::model()->findAll();
                $model = new TblUser();
                // $model->id = $row[0];
                $model->name = $row[0];
                $model->age = $row[1];
                $model->location = $row[2];
                if ($model->validate()) {
                    $model->save();
                } else {
                    //... code If an error in the preservation

                }
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my error :

```
exception 'CException' with message 'Property "TblUser.name" is not defined.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\base\CComponent.php:183
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\db\ar\...
```

my model:

```
<?php
class TblUser extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'tbl_user';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {

        return array(
            array('name, age, location', 'required'),
            array('age', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('name, location', 'length', 'max'=>100),

            array('name, age, location', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'name' => 'Name',
            'age' => 'Age',
            'location' => 'Location',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     *
     * Typical usecase:
     * - Initialize the model fields with values from filter form.
     * - Execute this method to get CActiveDataProvider instance which will filter
     * models according to data in model fields.
     * - Pass data provider to CGridView, CListView or any similar widget.
     *
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models
     * based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
        $criteria->compare('age',$this->age);
        $criteria->compare('location',$this->location,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * Please note that you should have this exact method in all your CActiveRecord descendants!
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return TblUser the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
}
```

Please ... provide any idea to fix this?

thanks!

Comment: Open your model and see what properties does it have?

Comment: u can see the model in question.. i've update that..

Comment: Does your table actually have `name` field?

Comment: yes, i have.. i generate that model using gii

Comment: Do you solved your question?

Comment: yup! hehe, but sadly no one gv me a answer